# UWP Listview binding error

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my UWP app mainpage xaml I try to bind an  `ObservableCollection<BluetoothLEDevice> BleDeviceList` to a listview.
If I run my app I get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice' to type 'UWPsimpleBLE_exampleWithSomeControls.MainPage'.
>      at UWPsimpleBLE_exampleWithSomeControls.MainPage.MainPage_obj2_Bindings.SetDataRoot(Object newDataRoot)
>      at UWPsimpleBLE_exampleWithSomeControls.MainPage.MainPage_obj2_Bindings.ProcessBindings(Object item, Int32 itemIndex, Int32 phase, Int32& nextPhase)

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:MainPage">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=BleDevice.Name }" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" />
            <StackPanel Margin="20,20,0,0">
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind BleDevice.BluetoothAddress.ToString()}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" />-->
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind BleDevice.ConnectionStatus}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" />-->
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>



 <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFDED7D7" 
                  BorderBrush="#FFF88686" Foreground="Black" 
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind BleDeviceList}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListDataTemplate }">
        </ListView>
```

If i comment out the line TextBlock Text.. The error is gone,so I must be doing something wrong with my binding

Comment: You set x:DataType="local:MainPage". And that is why the error message says that it cannot be converted... Have you tried x:DataType with BluetoothLEDevice?

Comment: This one here may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth  (see "DataTemplate and x:DataType")

Comment: @gregkalapos tryed that, but the only  possible are app and mainpage.

Comment: Did you import the namespace of the class with "xmlns:..." at the top of the XAML page?

Comment: @gregkalapos yes i have:  
     x:Class="UWPsimpleBLE_exampleWithSomeControls.MainPage"

Comment: You should import Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice, not the MainPage. Although I'm not sure if it's a good idea to bind BluetoothLEDevice directly... maybe a class that only contains BluetoothAddress and ConnectionStatus (...plus what you need) would be better. But anyway.. as a first try I'd suggest importing the BluetoothLEDevice and change x:DataType to that. Then you can refine it...

Comment: @GrooverFromHolland What about if you remove the DataType code  ` x:DataType="local:MainPage"` from `DataTemplate` resource? What @gregkalapos has mentioned, that is absolutely correct. If you want to specificity the `DataType` to `DataTemplate` then it should be defined with correct type (with namespace defined).

Comment: OK credit to @gregkalapos,added     xmlns:local="using:Windows.Devices.Bluetooth",
changed DataType="local:BluetoothLEDevice"
and Text="{x:Bind Path=Name } and now it is OK

Comment: Great! I'm happy to see that we made it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the solution was to change the x:DataType from `MainPage` to `BluetoothLEDevice` class. Additionally the `BluetoothLEDevice` class also had to be imported. In case of x:Bind you have to define the type of the class that you bind to and in this case the correct class was `BluetoothLEDevice`.

So this should be the code which does the job:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:BluetoothLEDevice">
```

And this line makes the `BluetoothLEDevice` class visible within the XAML page:

```
xmlns:local="using:Windows.Devices.Bluetooth"
```

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) describes x:Binds with DataTemplates (especially the  "DataTemplate and x:DataType" part).